# Inheritance in CSS properties

Tags: css, html

Here, In this example I have two divisions where one is nested within another. I'm calling the outer division a parent and the division which is nested a child.

**CSS**

```
/* for parent div tag*/
#parent{
        width: 500px;
        height: 300px;
        z-index: 1;
        background-color: #CCC;
        border:thin solid black;
        margin:25px;
        padding:20px;
}

/* for child div tag */
#child{
        border:thin solid #F00;
        height:50px;
        background-color:#FFC;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- Start of parent tag -->
<div id="parent">
<p> This is parent div tag. </p>

<!-- Child div tag -->
<div id="child">
<p> This is child div tag. </p>
</div>

<!-- End of parent tag. -->
</div>
```

It looks like this in the web browser:

[image]

My question is: How does the child div tag gets the size of it's width? Is it because of inheritance from the parent div tag or is it just by default behavior that it will expand up to the parent div container if you don't specify a width?

Comment: It's the default behaviour of all display:block elements to stretch as far as the parent container allows, yes.

Comment: here is an easy test, where the width is not set for the parent: http://jsfiddle.net/crazytonyi/XxNnu/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Width cannot be inherited. What you are seeing is default behavior.

[**See the specs on block level elements**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-boxes)

> "Each block-level element generates a principal block-level box that contains descendant boxes and generated content and is also the box involved in any positioning scheme." -- W3C

By default, block elements have a width of `100%`. That means that if a width isn't specified, it will be `100%` of the parent.

In this case, the parent's width is `542px`.

The calculation is based on `width:500px;` + `padding-left:20px;`+ `padding-right:20px;` +`border 2px;`

[image]

The child's width is exactly `500px`. (`100%` of the parents width - minus `padding`/`border`).

[image]

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/RWC7w/) You can play around with it and inspect the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, block level elements will expand to the width that the parent will let them (width minus padding).

Edit: if you want the child to only be as width as it contents, add `display: inline-block` to it (also check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/VeK7Y/)).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the div is by default a block element. And because you didn't specify width its value is "auto". This means that the browser calculates the width and normally that's 100% of the width of the parent element.